# How to create a 2d array from 2 lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have two lists with word tokens of two sentences.

```
l1 = ['car', 'consumer', 'majority', 'prefer', 'red']
l2 = ['car', 'customer', 'maximum', 'preferred', 'red']
```

I want to compare the elements of these two lists, compare each word pair [(car, car) (car, customer)...] and compute similarity, if two words are similar score is one else compute the score to zero.

I am trying to create a 2d array where no. of rows represent words of l2 and no. of columns represent words of l1. Initially the values in the array are set to zero and then fill the array with the score by comparing each word pair.

I am trying to create a program but I am getting errors.

```
rows, cols = (len(l1),len(l2))
arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
for j in arr:
   for i in j:
      if i==j:
         result = 1
      else:
         result = 0
      arr.append(result)
 print(arr)
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You should go through a tutorial. Here's a simple ansswer `arr = [[int(i==j) for i in l1] for j in l2]`

Comment: Do you really want the array, or do you just want the score? Your code at present is very confused but never really looks at the arrays you actually want to examine.

Comment: I want to compute the score of each word pairs and store them in an array

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what you want :

```
l1 = ['car', 'consumer', 'majority', 'prefer', 'red']
l2 = ['car', 'customer', 'maximum', 'preferred', 'red']

l3 = list(zip(l1,l2))

for tup in l3[:]:
    if tup[0] == tup[1]:
        l3.remove(tup)

print(l3)
```

Comment: yep, I was going to suggest the same +1

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this?

```
arr = [1 if x == y else 0 for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]
```

Output:

```
[1,0,0,0,1]
```